# Output an ASCII "splat"

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

If you throw an ASCII egg in a given direction, you end up with an **ASCII splat of size *n***. It "starts" with one `o` (the yolk), and continues in a given direction with "lines" consisting of 2 up to *n* `*`'s. The `*`'s are separated by one "space", and the `o` and all the "lines" of `*`'s are separated by "lines" of "space".

The direction of the splat can be any one of eight directions from `o`, for example:

```
1 2 3
4 o 5
6 7 8
```

Here are examples of ASCII splats of size 4 in directions `5`, `2` and `3` respectively. On the left is the actual ASCII splat, and on the right is the same splat but with the "lines" of "space" replaced with actual "lines" (i.e. `-` or `\` or `|` depending on the direction) just to clarify what is meant by a "line" of space.

```
Size 4, direction 5
      *      | | |*
    *        | |*| 
  *   *      |*| |*
o   *       o| |*| 
  *   *      |*| |*
    *        | |*| 
      *      | | |*

Size 4, direction 2
* * * *     * * * *
            -------
 * * *       * * *
            -------
  * *         * *
            -------
   o           o

Size 4, direction 3   
*           *      
            \
* *         *\*    
            \ \
* * *       *\*\*
            \ \ \ 
o * * *     o\*\*\*
```

### Challenge

Given *n ≥ 1* and one of the 8 possible directions, write a function or program that outputs the ASCII splat of size *n* in the given direction.

### Input and output

Any consistent, reasonable input format is allowed. You don't need to map directions to the integers 1 to 8 in the same way I did - if some other way of specifying the direction is easier, go ahead. But say what you did if it isn't clear.

The output will consist of `o`, `*`, spaces (U+0020) and newlines (U+000A) that produce the ASCII splat. Leading, trailing, otherwise extra whitespace is permitted on any line.

### Rules

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Standard rules apply.

#### More examples

```
Size 1, any direction
o

Size 3, direction 6
* * o

  * *

    *

Size 5, direction 7
    o    

   * *

  * * *

 * * * *

* * * * *
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
↘ＥＮ×*⊕ιＭ↗oＵＥ¬﹪η²⟲η
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYyxDoIwFEV3v6Lp9DB1MUyw6sBQYohOxqGWF9uk9JH6QP@@Nninc4ZzrTPJkgk5X5KPDM2JPnHwL8dKaDNDF@eF@2V6YoJKiauf8A1yL5Xook04YWQcwVdl7U7TitDc5q0v/r@UJAufv4xxhJ4YNI1LIHBKHLdsIDaM4Ko253utRP3IhzX8AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
↘ＥＮ×*⊕ι
```

Draw a diagonal triangle of splats.

```
Ｍ↗o
```

Place the egg.

```
ＵＥ¬﹪η²
```

For even rotations, expand the splat horizontally to match the output requirement. This requirement doesn't match Charcoal's usual expectations. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMPKJb88LygzPaNER8E3sUDDM6@gtMSvNDcptUhDU0chJDM3tVhDSUtJR8EzL7koNTc1ryQ1RSNTEwisuXzzy1I1rEILwPqBfIiRSvlKQHZQfkliSSqqeZrW//@bcJn81y3LAQA) (verbose) for how it looks without.

```
⟲η
```

Rotate the splat as required, using the following code for directions:

```
321
4o0
567
```

This <s>37</s> 31-byte version avoids extraneous whitespace by only rotating in right angles:

```
¿﹪η²Ｇ↘←θ*«↘Ｅθ×*⊕ι↗»oＵＥ¹﹪η²⟲⊗÷η²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY49C8IwFEVn8ytCpxeJg@LUrnUoWBDRSRxi@2wDaV5tY1XE3x7jx6BvuXA59/CKWnUFKeO9PnLIqTwbglrymRBstCJzq8hCnNLFrnVVO8njJR5DnCSPxpFIGJoe@T2wnbbuj8xVCwHb6AZ7CLDkmS06bNA6LEGLcAkb5TQgxNv2PQrFg31MEb3si6tDW8I02H5fS9ianHIIKZ0PJtgy61I96BK/gEi8380ln@/9ZDBP) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 37 bytes

```
”*ẋK¥ⱮmṠ©}”oḷ""LḶ⁶ẋƲ;"ṚƊ®¡z⁶K€ZU$A}¡Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVEArv9qZWxsef//4oCdKuG6i0vCpeKxrm3huaDCqX3igJ1v4bi3IiJM4bi24oG24bqLxrI7IuG5msaKwq7CoXrigbZL4oKsWlUkQX3CoVn///81/zM)

Directions:

\$\left[\begin{array}c1&2&3\\4&\circ&5\\6&7&8\end{array}\right]\rightarrow\left[\begin{array}c-2&1&-3\\4&\circ&2\\-1&3&-4\end{array}\right]\$

Answer (score 2):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 25 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
Ｈ*×］oｎ╶２％？！／ ＊］ ＊／｝⤢ ＊⁷⇵⟳
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjI4KiVENyV1RkYzRG8ldUZGNEUldTI1NzYldUZGMTIldUZGMDUldUZGMUYldUZGMDEldUZGMEYlMjAldUZGMEEldUZGM0QlMjAldUZGMEEldUZGMEYldUZGNUQldTI5MjIlMjAldUZGMEEldTIwNzcldTIxRjUldTI3RjM_,i=MTAlMEE4,v=8)

The directions are as follows:

```
7 6 1
4 ∘ 8
5 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 185 bytes

```python
lambda n,d:'\n'.join(g([(d/4*(n+~j)*' '+('*o'[[j>n-2,j<1][d/4]]+' *'*j)*i).ljust(2*n-1)for j in range(n)for i in(0,1)][1:],d%4))
g=lambda a,n:n and g(map(''.join,zip(*a))[::-1],n-1)or a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY/BbsIwEETP5St8qXbX2dA6yqGyoD9ifDByE2zBJgrpoT30190A4fo0ejMz/synQZrS7Q/lHC7HGJRwtHAQ2OYhCfboML61GqX6y6RBQYWgB3Auf0rdcN4Z75aA9xUoDXrJJNqe8/d1xkZLbagbJpVVEjUF6b9Q7iAtAN/ZkHfGeo6vLdGm368TAosVFSSqHi9hRHiM4d80og5EztraeL7ZF1coT@Na8UF28zJOSWaV@HaFO2w50QpL@Qc)

The numbering is from 0 to 7, as follows:

```python
1 6 0
7 o 5
2 4 3
```

Notes: Most of the work is to generate the basic patterns for (in my numbering system) `0` and `4`. Then the function `g` rotates the array `a` 90 degrees `d%4` times via recursion to generate the other results.